# SQL minus operator equivalent in laravel eloquent context

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am looking for a way to MINUS two query results in laravel. I didn't find a good result in my google search. This is the code that I have tested.

```
$disconnectedOrderItems = DB::table( DB::raw("{$allOrderItems->toSql()} MINUS {$connectedOrderItems->toSql()}"))
        ->mergeBindings($allOrderItems->getQuery())
        ->mergeBindings($connectedOrderItems->getQuery())
        ->get();
```

which produces syntax error:
**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation**

Comment: Can't you just write an Anti-Join?

Comment: @TheImpaler I have multiple conditions and reversing all those doesn't seem straightforward.

Comment: r u using mysql as driver?

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes, I do.

Comment: It seems MySQL doesn’t support the MINUS  operator.

Comment: can u plz post the $allOrderItems and $connectedOrderItems sqls